# How to specify ranges to java.util.Random?

Tags: java, android, random

I don't know why Java's designers didn't design java.util.Random objects to return random numbers like this:

`rand.nextInt(minValue, maxValue);`

I don't understand how to pass min and max values to this function. I've seen this recommended:

`random.nextInt(max + 1 - (min)) + min`

but what does that mean? Does that mean:

`random.nextInt(FULL_RANGE + 1) + START_OF_RANGE`

For example, if I wanted to generate values between -1 and 1, inclusive, is this how I do it:

`int oneOfThreeChoices = rand.nextInt(1 + 1 + 1) - 1;`

Comment: Regarding "what does that mean": `max - min + 1` is the size of the range. E.g., if you want values in the range `[1, 4]` then you want 4 different values (1, 2, 3, 4) -- that's `4 - 1 + 1`. Now, since the arg to nextInt is exclusive, you want to pass in 4. This gets you values in {0, 1, 2, 3}, so whatever value from that you get, you just shift it up 1 (ie, `min`) to get values in {1, 2, 3, 4}.

Comment: The answer that is linked by the mods is a much more complicated question. The top answer is irrelevant. How is that helpful? It doesn't help me.

Comment: How is it irrelevant? As far as I can tell, your question is basically "how do I generate a random int in a given min/max range?" If that's your question, the linked duplicate answers it, and my comment here even explains it a bit by example. If that's not your question, what is?

Answer (score 3):

The API provides sufficient tools for you to complete this task.  If you want an random int on the range [a,b], inclusive on both ends, use

```
int n = random.nextInt(b-a+1) + a
```

assuming that `random` is an object previously declared to be of type `java.util.Random`.

Answer (score 2):

`random.nextInt(bound)` returns random number from 0 to `bound` (exclusive). For example `random.nextInt(10)` returns random number from 0 to 9.

So, if you want to return number from 5 to 15 (inclusive) just say

```
random.nextInt(11) + 5
```

Why java designers have not included more convenient API to JDK? I think because the way explained here is pretty simple and obvious.